# Can anyone explain in simple and easy words that what is the difference between ../ and ./ when including files?

Tags: javascript, php, css

As we know that ../ means one step back and / means the current place but i am confused about the ./ when working with my web site and found that. Can anyone explain ?

Comment: `.` is what means "the current directory", not `/`, so `./` is how you make a path that starts at the current directory and descends into a subdirectory.

Comment: http://www.coffeecup.com/help/articles/absolute-vs-relative-pathslinks/

Answer (score 1):

`.` means this directory

`..` means the parent directory

`/` is the directory separator (for Linux/Unix)

When using `include "file.php";` php will look in the current directory and in his configured include path for a file named `file.php`

When using `include "./file.php";` php will look in the current directory (and only there) for a file named `file.php`

if you use `include "../file.php";` php will look in the parent directory for a file named `file.php`

Answer (score 0):

`./` - current directory.

`/` - it is root directory (it used often for concatenating paths as directory separator, because previous path doesn't contain leading slash, for example host + '/' + cssFile).

Answer (score 0):

- `/` represents the root of a folder structure. For a website, it's the
  root folder, where you would usually put the index.html of the
  landing page.
- `./` represents the 'current' folder, relative with the
  current file. If you open the 'index.html' file in the root folder,
  then `./` will be the same as `/`. If you are in a subfolder of the
  root, like `/css/` for example, then `./` will be the same as
  `/css/`.
- `../` represents the parent folder. If you are in `/css/`,
  then `../` will be the same as `/`, the root folder.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say this is your working on a file called process.php in the following directory:

`/app/form/process.php`

The this is what those symbols mean:

`/` = root directory, or in the example: `/`

`./` = current directory, or in the example: `/app/form/`

`../` = one directory back, in the example: `app/`

Comment: Clear and concise examples.

Comment: ... and wrong. / is /, not /app, ./ is /app/form/, not /form/, and ../ is /app/, not /form

Comment: @CCH thanks for pointing that out